# Angular 2 4 5 - How to save search results when reloading page or clicking “back” button with Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I WANT How to search results when back to previous page.

example)

boardListUrl : /board

boardDetailUrl : /board/detail/:id

---

1. 'title' search button ON boardListUrl

   ex) 'title' search button click : 'hello' search
         ( Called backand server REST api )

   ==> boardListUrl : /board

   ```
      tables datas: "hello ~" / "hello 2 ~" / "hello  3~" /
   ```
2. table row click =>  boardDetailUrl page

   ex) /board/detail/:1

   boardDetailUrl page exist 'Back Page' Button
3. 'Back Page' Button  Click

==> I WANT [ boardListUrl page + "hello" search Results Or search word : 'hello' ]

How to previous page with search word(search parameter) OR search Datas

Answer (score 1):

You can store your results in `localStorage` and use it anywhere. For ex: 
`localStorage.setItem("searchResults", JSON.stringify(yourResults));` 
and get it in the component 
`let rs = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchResult'))`

Comment: Thank you!!. 

previous Page with previous searchResults it generally used on angular?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm also a newbie in angular.

Comment: thank you. 

I have to think a lot.

currently, 
detail page is not a popup(modal).
( because, detail page in many elements )

Comment: You should separate the detail component into small components and use @Input

Comment: You can use a "service", not localStorage

Comment: @Eliseo , could you give me an example about service to store value? I have some problems to store value if go to previous page without using localStorage

Answer (score 1):

The key to "get the old state" in a component is using a service and implement OnInit and OnDestroy

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

variableState:any; //<--a variable we can "conserv"
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService){}
ngOnInit() {
    //if the service has the variable take the value, else null
    this.variableState=this.sharedService.variableState?this.sharedService.variableState:null;
}
ngOnDestroy{
   //In the destroy, we use the service to set the variable
   this.sharedService.variableState=this.variableState;
}
```

The service is so easy like

```
@Injectable()
export class sharedService{
variableState:any;
}
```

Well, we needn't make a SharedService only to shared variables, we can use, e.g. the same service that get the data just adding a public variable.

NOTE: Our variableState can be an Object too