# How to pass data between component when the parent is a mat component (Angular Material)?

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-material

I am new to Angular and do not know the exact jargon for my situation. So sorry in advance and bear with me a little. I appreciate your help.

I have an angular app to edit and I want to send data from a child component to the parent to store it and reuse it if needed. I couldn't simply use `@Input` or `@output new EventEmitter` because I only get to call the child through routing:

I have a navbar component (parent here) which call my childComponent. I simplified it in the below snippet:

**# top-nav.component.html**

```
<mat-toolbar class="top-nav">
  <button mat-button  [routerLink]="['/Child_Component']">Home Button</button>
```

I do not know how to listen to the event emitter in this case.
I already setup the emitter as follows:

**in childComponent.ts:**

```
  @Output() activeTabIndex = new EventEmitter<number>()
  public tabChanged(tabChangeEvent: MatTabChangeEvent) {
    this.activeTabIndex.emit(tabChangeEvent.index)
  }
```

**in childComponent.html**

```
<mat-tab-group #tabGroup  [(selectedIndex)]="currentTabIndex" (selectedTabChange)="tabChanged($event)" >
```

As you might have guessed I want to save the index for the last viewed tab by the users, and when they were done doing stuff with the menu inside each tab, and pressed the home button (showed in top-nav.component.html) to see the tabs again, show them the last viewed tab (not the tab with index 0).

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's a typical case to "store" the last situation in a service. The services are living along the life of the application, so you can use OnInit and OnDestroy, se, e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959178/angular-2-4-5-how-to-save-search-results-when-reloading-page-or-clicking-back/50962647#50962647)